# Git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph doesn't show branches with lines only asterisks

Tags: git, logging, branch

When I run:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

I see this output:

```
* 159d15f (origin/include-user-destinations, include-user-destinations) Add destination to Scotland
* 16b251a Add destinations to Florida and Paris
* 650a8de (HEAD -> master, upstream/master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Update index.html
* 574c456 changed travel destinations
* 9039cf9 changed to Sao Paolo
* b2d0353 Add animation to destination headings
* 1204be0 Style destinations
* 7562e21 Add starting destinations
* 5e9b201 Initial commit
```

Which is a flat list of commits without showing all branches. However, in the past the output used to have red lines that would show a branch separated from the master; something similar to this (obviously this is the output from a different repo):

```
* e6122521 (HEAD -> master) 
*   f533d9eb 
|\
|/|
* |   7c2cb982 Merge branch 
|\ \
```

I know I have a branch because when I run `$ git branch` it shows:

```
include-user-destinations
* master
```

My guess is that I have made a change to my git config that has changed the output. Any ideas on how I can show the branch lines again?

Comment: Look at your top 3 commits: your branch `include-user-destinations` is 2 commits ahead of `master` and can be fast-forwarded. There is a linear history because the branches are linearly connected. Try adding a commit to master and then running the log command again, you'll see branching.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, `git log` doesn't bother with the *lines* until it needs them.  See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253135/1256452) to [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).  Only a few commits have lines between them, when the asterisks don't line right up one atop another.

In some rare cases, this particular output *can* be ambiguous.  Run `git log --graph` without `--oneline` to eliminate the ambiguity, or use one of those fancy graph-drawers that always includes lines, if you think you have such a case.